# LogJ2: log to console in development only

Tags: java, log4j2

In Log4J2, is there a simple way to log to the Console in development only?
I would like to have the appender in the configuration, only if I'm in my dev environment (which can be found via a System property, for example).

In logback, I had an optional include which was adding the Console appender to the root logger, so it was pretty convenient and not intrusive at all.
Is there something something similar in Log4J2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to configure `RoutingAppender` along with `ConsoleAppender` and any `FileAppender` like `RollingFileAppender`.

Below is sample `log4j2.xml` configuration file with `RoutingAppender` -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configuration>

<Configuration status="warn" name="xml_configuration">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">./log/</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}app.log"
            filePattern="${basePath}app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz">

            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}    %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg%n" />

            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                    modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>


        <Console name="consoleLogger" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg%n" />
        </Console>

        <Routing name="RoutingLogger">
            <!-- Condition is - if isDevEnv VM argument is true (-isDevEnv=true), 
                then log messages in console else log messages in file -->
            <Script name="RoutingCondition" language="JavaScript"><![CDATA[
                var imports = new JavaImporter(java.lang);
                with (imports) {
                    System.getProperty("isDevEnv") == "true" ? "console" : "file";
                }]]>
            </Script>
            <Routes>
                <Route ref="consoleLogger" key="console" />
                <Route ref="fileLogger" key="file" />
            </Routes>
        </Routing>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="mypackage" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RoutingLogger" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RoutingLogger" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Routing of logs will be done based on the value of `isDevEnv VM argument`. If `isDevEnv VM argument` is `true` (`-DisDevEnv=true`), then log messages in console else log messages in file.

So, in your development environment, you can set this `VM argument` with `true` value for enabling logging in console. For production environment, no need to set this `VM argument`.

Answer (score -1):

You could:

1. Remove all the ConsoleLogger from your configurations and add it programmatically (see example below) - *you can't remove it programmatically*
2. Load the right configuration reading a the right file manually
3. Load the right configuration file via [system property](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)
4. If you use maven you can rename the file programmatically before lunching

Example 1:

```
    final LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final Configuration loggerContextConfiguration = loggerContext.getConfiguration();
    final Layout layout = PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout();
    final Appender appender = ConsoleAppender.createDefaultAppenderForLayout(layout);
    appender.start();
    loggerContextConfiguration.addAppender(appender);
    loggerContextConfiguration.getLoggers().values().forEach(l -> l.addAppender(appender, Level.DEBUG, null));
    loggerContext.updateLoggers();
```

Example 2:

```
Configurator.initialize(null, "./resources/log4j2-dev.xml");
```

Comment: Changing the configuration programmatically would involve writing code that is based on the implementation of log4j2 rather than relying on just the public API and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Yes, this is a #2 variant solution